How to verify if sets satisfying cardinality condition exist?
I am trying to find out if sets satisfying the following properties exist:

Call the sets $A_1, \ldots, A_{20}$ and $B_1, \ldots, B_{20}$.
For each $i \in \{1, \ldots, 20\}$, $|A_i| \in \{1,2\}, |B_i| = 3 - |A_i|$.
$|A_1 \cup A_2 \ldots \cup B_{20}| = 15$
Each $x \in |A_1 \cup A_2 \ldots \cup B_{20}|$ occurs in exactly 4 of the $A_1 \ldots, B_{20}$

How do I go about doing this? I have tried using Principle of inclusion and exclusion, but it doesn't really seem to help in this scenario, since it gives you the exact cardinality of $A_1 \cup A_2 \ldots \cup B_{20}$ which doesn't help much.
For context, I am trying to generate an algorithm for a computer science project. I don't want to brute force the problem, because I need it to work for higher numbers which might take several hours to compute, so I am wondering if there is a clean mathematical procedure / existence conditions.

Simulposted to mathstack, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5008277/how-to-verify-if-sets-satisfying-cardinality-conditions-exist in violation of site rules.

In other words, you are asking whether there is a bipartite graph with $15$ vertices on one side (all of degree $4$) and $40$ vertices on the other side ($20$ of degree $1$ and $20$ of degree $2$.) A criterion for this sort of question is given by the Gale–Ryser theorem.
